# Mandar multiples archivos en Java (Socket)

Tags: java, socket

tengo este código. El cliente envía correctamente los archivos, el problema es el servidor.
Estoy enviando multiples archivos usando el mismo método con un for.

Código para mandar.

```
private void sendFile(File file) throws Exception {
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[8192];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
        dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
        int read;
        while((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) != -1){
            dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Código de recepción (este es el que está fallando):

```
private void receiveFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        int count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or 4096, or more
        while ((count = input.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Código desde donde se ejecuta el receiveFile:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            char type = input.readChar();
            if (type == 's') {
                int lenght = input.readInt();
                String message = receive(type, lenght);

                String user_info = "[USER_INFO] ";
                if (message.contains(user_info)) {
                    String s = message.replace(user_info, "");
                    String[] values = s.split("\\|");
                    String a = values[0];
                    String b = values[1];

                    user.setDeviceName(a);
                    user.setAndroidVersion(b);
                    Main.getMySQL().addUser(user);
                }
                System.out.println("[RECEIVING MESSAGE] " + message);
            }
            else if (type == 'f') {
                String fileName = input.readUTF();
                receiveFile(fileName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ignored) {}
    finally {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Inicialización del input/output:

```
private final Socket socket;
private final DataInputStream input;
private final DataOutputStream output;
private final User user;

public Client(Socket socket) throws Exception {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    this.output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    this.user = new User();
}
```

El error en concreto es que el servidor no recibe los archivos correctamente.
Los archivos son creados pero dañados y a veces pesan 0kb.

Comment: Por lo que veo envías a través del mismo stream el nombre del fichero (texto), el tamaño del array/buffer (un int, no sé para qué) y luego mandas los datos del fichero. El receptor sólo parece esperar los datos del fichero.

Comment: Yo consideraría usar ZipOutputStream y ZipInputStream para enviar los archivos, de forma que no tengas que montarte tú la lógica de "aquí empieza el archivo, éste es el nombre, estos son los datos, aquí acaba el archivo, aquí empieza el archivo siguiente..."

Comment: @SJuan76 estoy de acuerdo: a menos que esto sea un ejercicio para practicar, reinventar un protocolo para intercambiar ficheros puede ser innecesariamente complejo

Comment: Tienen un ejemplo de código?